# Decimal one place input type only number Ionic 3 latest version (3.9.2) I'm using

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using ionic latest version 3.9.2. and I'm facing one problem. I have one input box. input type number, when user input in text box they allow only one digit after the decimal. and in input box maximum only one decimal allow not more than one.

```
Examples: 
1) 1407.1
2) 6449496.8
3) 1.1
```

Like this only user can input one digit after decimal

My Html Code

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>TECHLOG:</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [ngModel]="mymodel" (ngModelChange)="onChangeTech($event)"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

My ts file code

```
  onChangeTech(event) {
    alert(event)
  }
```

In the alert, i got the number what ever I type, but don't know how to forcefully stop after one decimal in my input box.

Comment: Can you show the `code`?

Comment: Please check my code, and we can fix this only in HTML side?.Thanks

Comment: Can you show the `mymodel` details also? `code` on `.ts` file?

Comment: I have not used mymodel anywhere in my .ts without [ngModel]="mymodel" 
  My change function was not called that's why I had put that. I'm new in ionic.

Comment: Do you need to restrict to a user to input `only 1` decimal place on the text input? e.g. `10.2`?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want exactly like your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**text-mask**](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme) module.Please try that and let me know.

[**Demo Page from the Doc**](https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/)

> npm i angular2-text-mask --save

*Then, import it into your @NgModule:*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    TextMaskModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this just right now and I will let you know.

Comment: I can't understand your example: this line we have to put in template: `
    <input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="text"/>
  `

Comment: Just replace `input` with `ion-input`.

Comment: you have any other simple example when I use input at that time my app throws an error.

Comment: OK, I'll create a sample and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks, Please help me I really stuck in this from last 2 days but no luck. I'm using ionic latest version.
"ionic": "3.9.2",
"typescript": "2.3.4"

Answer (score -1):

This way is not correct 100%. It will round the user input (ex. 1.57 --> 1.6). And it can not handle the wrong input (ex. 1.2.3454). But, it is a fast and simple way.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('numberInput');
input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  let value = parseFloat(input.value);
  if (value) {
    input.value = parseFloat(value.toFixed(1));
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numberInput" step="0.1" />
```

Comment: It is working on ionic 3? and thanks for sharing your example with me I will let you know it's working or not.

Comment: It is just javascript. And Ionic is a javascript framework.

Comment: Hi, Duannx, I have tried this but this logic was not forcefully stopped me decimal one place input type. when user input one decimal then after user can not enter a number after one decimal.

Comment: Oh. I thought it is what you want. User just can input a number with only one decimal digit.